# Array won't return ref value (bash)

Tags: arrays, bash

I've been trying to storage my data in an array as follows:

```
table="$1"
reference="$2"
directory="$3"

declare -A count

$reference | while read line; do
    ref=`echo $line | cut -d " " -f1`
    key=`echo $line | cut -d " " -f4`
    count=([$key]=$ref)
    echo $ref
    echo $key
    echo "${count[$key]}"
 done
```

This works, I do the prints and for each key I got the value I want. Then, I try to use with some keys:

```
cat $table | while read line; do
    sample=`echo $line | cut -d "_" -f1`
    id=${count[$line]}
    echo $sample
    echo $line
    echo $id
    echo "works"
done
```

Here is the problem: Sample is echoed perfectly, just as are $line and "works". But $id is not working, and I have no idea what I am missing here

Answer (score 1):

That's because whatever you store in `count` are gone as soon as the subshell that runs the while loop exits. The while loop that you pipe into runs in a subshell. So any variables you "set" won't be available outside if it. That means when you later use `count`, it doesn't have any elements.

Change the loop to:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    ref=`echo $line | cut -d " " -f1`
    key=`echo $line | cut -d " " -f4`
    count["$key"]="$ref"
    echo $ref
    echo $key
    echo "${count[$key]}"
 done < "${reference}"
```

Similarly change in the other loop.

I am assuming `reference` is a file. If `reference` is actually the text you want to read the "lines" from then you can use [*here strings*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    ...
    ...  
done <<< "${reference}"
```

Comment: shouldn't `declare -A count` deal with that?

Comment: No. It just declares an array. It's not related to the issue. The `count` that's updated inside the loop is *not* same one you have outside. Inside the subshell, it's a different variable and doesn't exist once the subshell exits.

Comment: Not to mention that `count=(...)` is creating a **new** array each time and blowing up any old contents.

Comment: @EtanReisner Thanks for pointing it out. I didn't see it at all. I think, it should be fine now.

Comment: Still get the bad array subscript here `count["$key"]="$ref"`

Comment: Yeah, that's not it. You want `count+=(["$key"]="$ref")` I believe.

Comment: Still, `[]=: bad array subscript`

Comment: @MLMH I am not quite sure what you want to do with the array. Does your `key` and `ref` have values and not empty? Do you want append to an existing array and perhaps Etan's suggestion works?

Comment: I have a tab separated file, with some columns. The first one is going to be the value to my key (the 4th column). I just want an array where I can look for a key afterwars (the second loop)

Comment: @MLMH Can you give a short example of how the `reference` and `table` files look like? I don't see any issues with my own test of your loop.